# Laravel Plus Reactjs server Side rendering plus Less and ant Design

Tags: reactjs, laravel, less, antd

First i'm sorry if i did not tag the topic correctly. So I have  a frontend app built with Reactjs, ant design and less. And i am using laravel on  API basis. The issue is this laravel needs csrf token to authenticate the user and since they on different servers it difficult. I am stuck at this point also since they on localhost i am getting issues with the request methods. `Post Method` request from the client server to the goes through `options` method before getting to the post method of the endpoint 
ie `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login)`
It will go to options method first before going to post. Is this a cors error if yes how do i handle cors.

Secondly if the above is a wrong practice, I have tried laravel preset for reactjs but to get less running with mix is difficult as  most of ant design customization are done in less so I will really appreciate any assistance concerning this issue.

How to setup either mix.js or Client/ server side rendering

Comment: follow this link to handle cors `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors`

Comment: I have done that what about csrf. Thanks